# Difference between onScroll() and onFling() of GestureDetector

Tags: android, android-gesture

What is the difference between `onScroll()` and `onFling()` in the `GestureDetector` interface?
When I print out the events they are showing the exact same things. At least the last `onScroll()` and the `onFling()`.

The only true difference I noticed is that `onScroll()` is called much more often, fling always just one time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference between **`Scroll`** and **`fling`**

**onFling**: is that the user lifts his finger in the end of the movement (that is the reason for what `onFling` is called one time).

**onScroll**: is the general process of moving the viewport (that is, the 'window' of content you're looking at).

> **[Understand Scrolling Terminology](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html#term)** "Scrolling" is a word that can take on different meanings in Android, depending on the context.
>
> **Scrolling** is the general process of moving the viewport (that is, the
>   'window' of content you're looking at). When scrolling is in both the
>   x and y axes, it's called panning. The sample application provided
>   with this class, [InteractiveChart](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/InteractiveChart/src/com/example/android/interactivechart/), illustrates two different types of
>   scrolling, dragging and flinging:
>
> - **Dragging** is the type of scrolling that occurs when a user drags her
>     finger across the touch screen. Simple dragging is often implemented
>     by overriding onScroll() in GestureDetector.OnGestureListener. For
>     more discussion of dragging, see Dragging and Scaling.
> - **Flinging** is the type of scrolling that occurs when a user drags and lifts her finger
>     quickly. After the user lifts her finger, you generally want to keep
>     scrolling (moving the viewport), but decelerate until the viewport
>     stops moving. Flinging can be implemented by overriding onFling() in
>     GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, and by using a scroller object.